# Avoiding Zombies in BizTalk 2006 Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

I'm running BizTalk 2006, and I have an orchestration that receives a series of messages (orders) that are correlated on BTS.MessageType. On my delay shape, I check the time until midnight, which is the batch cut off. I'm getting occasional instances where I receive a message after the loop ends, and this is creating Zombie messages. I still need these messages to process, but in a new instance of the orchestration. I need some ideas of how to handle this gracefully.

Comment: Just as a side note, as an attempt at a hackish (non-graceful) solution, I put a schedule on the receive location to make sure that no messages are received after the orchestration leaves the loop. I know it isn't the best, but it seems to temporarily resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to correlate on the date (in addition to BTS.MessageType)

You would have to create a pipeline component that promotes the date without the time. But there could be some time window where messages would go "randomly" either to the old or new instance (for example if you have multiple BizTalk servers with slightly different times, or if the system clocks is resynchronized with a NTP source). To be safe, wait a few minutes before ending the previous day's instance.

If that window of overlap between the old and new instances is a problem, you should instead correlate on another value that changes only once a day, such as a Guid stored in a database and promoted by a pipeline component.

Otherwise, I've successfully used your "hackish" solution in past projects, as long as you can tolerate a small window where messages are queued and not processed immediately for a few minutes every day. In my case it was fine because messages are produced by american users during their work day, and sent by FTP or MSMQ. However if you have international users that sent messages by web services, then you may not have a time in the day where you probably won't receive anything, and the web services won't be able to queue the messages for later processing.